# how to parse JSON array in react?

Tags: javascript

I have created simple application in Reactjs, I want to parse JSON array values and remove all slash`(\)` could you please help me

```js
const jsonObject = {
  "account_create_view": [
    {
      "accounts": "[2092]",
      "fields_to_display": "[\"account_name\", \"company\"]",
      "filter_fields": "[{\"input\": \"account_name\", \"operator\": \"equals\", \"values\": [\"Prakruthi Resources - Saii Resources\"]}]",
      "id": 184,
      "unique_name": "acc_12_18",
      "view_name": " acc_12_18"
    }
  ]
};

// Convert the JSON object to a string, remove all backslashes, and parse it back to an object
const cleanedJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/\\/g, '');
const cleanedObject = JSON.parse(cleanedJsonString);

console.log(cleanedObject);
```

Comment: if i check console.log display this error "editview.js:54 SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 68 (line 1 column 69)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fetchData5 (editview.js:49:1)"

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is in the fields_to_display key there is `"[` and `]"`, which is not removed by your regex.

```js
const jsonObject = {
  "account_create_view": [
    {
      "accounts": "[2092]",
      "fields_to_display": "[\"account_name\", \"company\"]",
      "filter_fields": "[{\"input\": \"account_name\", \"operator\": \"equals\", \"values\": [\"Prakruthi Resources - Saii Resources\"]}]",
      "id": 184,
      "unique_name": "acc_12_18",
      "view_name": " acc_12_18"
    }
  ]
};

const cleanedJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
  .replace(/\\/g, '')
  .replace(/"\[/g, '[')
  .replace(/\]"/g, ']');
const cleanedObject = JSON.parse(cleanedJsonString);

console.log(cleanedObject);
```

Comment: Thanks Rumman Sadik you really genius.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the nested double quotes, eg: `"[\"account_name\", \"company\"]"`

When you remove the `\`, the double quotes inside are not being changed to single quotes and are not being removed, so you see that error. I would say changed the nested quotes to single quotes or let them be, those `\` only represent presence of quotes inside a string, in the frontend or in the output you do not see them. So, its okay to have them.